# Which one is faster "find" or "at" in unordered_map?

Tags: c++, find, unordered-map

I know that for an unordered map, "find" returns an iterator while "at" returns the mapped value. I am just curious about which one is faster.

Comment: Try both and benchmark each of them.

Comment: Also, you can read the source code.

Comment: Ah yeah, those are good ideas that I will try, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't choose between the two of them based on the speed, pick the method that better express your intention. When you use `at` you are assuming that the element is in the map (you get an exception otherwise). With `find` this is not the case.

Answer (score 7):

`find` is more likely to be noexcept.  In some compilers/platforms, noexcept functions can be made faster or simpler in code size, as the exception setup/catch/etc doesn't have to be set up.

If you find, then throw if missing, you'll get indistinguishable results.  If you at, then catch and branch, you'll probably be slower than find (if the compiler doesn't optimize the throw/catch out of existence).

The difference will be small, so you should pick which to call based on other considerations, unless the code is performance critical.  In that case, profile and teat, do not rely on theory or microbenchmarks.

Comment: *"`find` is more likely to be noexcept"* - the Standard documents which functions are `noexcept`, and `find` isn't one of them.  I don't see how it could be without requiring the key hash and comparison functions to be - but I don't think there're any such restrictions, and indeed the default implementations (i.e. `std::equal_to<>` , `std::hash<>`) aren't `noexcept`.

Comment: @tony sorry, bad use of keyword.  It is likely to be completely inlineable, and contain no throw statements, so require no exception handling machinery.

Comment: yup, that's a solid point... see where you were coming from now.  Cheers.

Comment: +1 But if you use `find`, get `my_container.end()` and have no idea of what to do with it, you still need some kind of error handling the standard way being throwing an exception, the non standard way being a mess :)

Comment: @dariop a lot of code gets by being error-oblivious, or having fallbacks, or creating-if-it-was-not-already-there, or the like.  Exceptions are for exceptional situations that cannot reasonably be handled locally.  Expecting an exception to occur is often a bad sign, in a sense.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

The following is the source code of both functions in VS2015 Community.

```
iterator find(const key_type& _Keyval)
    {   // find an element in mutable hash table that matches _Keyval
    return (lower_bound(_Keyval));
    }

mapped_type& at(const key_type& _Keyval)
    {   // find element matching _Keyval
    iterator _Where = _Mybase::lower_bound(_Keyval);
    if (_Where == _Mybase::end())
        _Xout_of_range("invalid unordered_map<K, T> key");
    return (_Where->second);
    }
```

As you can see, they are almost the same, and should have the same performances.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same.
If you check the documentation for [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/find/) and [at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/at/)

You can see that the complexity is:

> Average case: constant.
>   Worst case: linear in container size.